# Attempting to pass current record's ID from trigger to Class

Tags: apex, trigger, visual-workflow, class

Code novice here! I am trying to pass the OpportunityContactRole's Opportunity ID from a trigger to a class to a Flow. I would happily use a Process Builder to trigger the Flow but OCR's are yet to run by a PB.

The trigger will run whenever an OCR is added or edited. It should pass the OCR's Opportunity Id to the Class which should in turn pass the OCR's OpportunityId to a flow.

As you can see below, I haven't got very far, but here's what I have pieced together by reading other posts and code

Trigger:

```
Trigger Default on OpportunityContactRole after insert, after update){
 AddPrimaryContactToOpportunity.runFlow();
}
```

Class:

```
public class AddPrimaryContactToOpportunity { 
    public static void runFlow() {
        OpportunityContactRole currentRecord;

        public OpportunityContactRole getcurrentRecord(){
            return currentRecord;
        }

        Flow.Interview flow = new Flow.Interview.Update_Primary_Contact_lookup(new map<String,Object> 
                                                    {'recordId' => currentRecord.OpportunityId});     
        flow.start();
}
```

Appreciate any help here!

Edit - trigger syntax

Comment: I have some questions, your trigger code says it runs on the `Account` object. However, you're trying to get an `Opportunity` or `OpportunityContactRole` Id. Can you clarify a little bit or maybe you have to edit your code snippets

Comment: From the account trigger you can pass the list of accounts as a parameter to the run flow method (Triggers are designed for bulkification so the correct methodology is to assume there is always more then one account being inserted at once and handle them all at once)


AddPrimaryContactToOpportunity.runFlow(Trigger.new);

public static void runFlow(List<Accounts> acctList) {...} however you will have to query for the related OpportunityContactRole in the runFlow method using that Account Id of the accounts from the list

Comment: @BryanAnderson sorry, I got the trigger object incorrect. The trigger runs on the Opportunity Contact Role object.

Comment: @CalvinOKeefe sorry, I got the trigger object incorrect. The trigger runs on the Opportunity Contact Role object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the issue I see here is that calling a flow is not a bulkified process, but to get you a little further, here is you code reworked:

```
public class AddPrimaryContactToOpportunity { 
    public static void runFlow() {

        //I admit, this is not bulkified
        for(OpportunityContactRole ocr : Trigger.new)
        {
            Flow.Interview flow = new Flow.Interview.Update_Primary_Contact_lookup(new map<String,Object> 
                                                        {'recordId' => ocr.OpportunityId});     
            flow.start();
        }
}
```

I would also review the governor limits for Flows and see if your business process needs to be reworked https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.212.0.salesforce_vpm_guide.meta/salesforce_vpm_guide/vpm_admin_flow_limits.htm

Comment: Thank you @BryanAnderson! I made some small tweaks and that works. I will read up on the governor limits for Flows.

Comment: Thanks @UninvitedGuest, can you mark this as solved if it fixed your issue

Answer (score 2):

If anyone needs this in the future, here's the code:

Trigger

```
Trigger OppContactRoleTrigger on OpportunityContactRole (after insert, after update){
AddPrimaryContactToOpportunity.runFlow();
}
```

Class

```
public class AddPrimaryContactToOpportunity { 
public static void runFlow() {

    for(OpportunityContactRole ocr : (List<OpportunityContactRole>) Trigger.new){
        Flow.Interview flow = new Flow.Interview.Update_Primary_Contact_lookup(new map<String,Object> 
                                                    {'recordId' => ocr.OpportunityId});     
        flow.start();
    }
}
```

Test Class

```
@isTest
public class TestOppContactRoleTrigger {
static testMethod void insertAllRecords() {
    // Create Account
    Account acc                = new Account();      
    acc.Name                   = 'Test Acc';
    insert acc;

    // Create Contact
    Contact con                = new Contact();
    con.LastName               = 'Lasttest';
    insert con;

    // Create Opportunity
    Opportunity opp            = new Opportunity();
    opp.Name                   = 'Test Opp';
    opp.AccountId              = acc.id;
    opp.StageName              = 'Prospecting';
    opp.CloseDate              = System.today() + 5;
    insert opp;

    // Create OpportunityContactRole
    OpportunityContactRole ocr = new OpportunityContactRole();
    ocr.OpportunityId          = opp.id;
    ocr.ContactId              = con.id;
    ocr.isPrimary              = TRUE;
    insert ocr;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I tried your suggestion.

I am getting error on bluk upload.

```
    Public class RolleupsumLeads{

// When leads are inserted
Public static void afterinsert(List<Lead__c> Leads){
          Rolleuphandeler(Leads);
}
//handler method to call the Flow  
Public static void Rolleuphandeler(List<Lead__c> Leads){

   for (Lead__c Ld : (List<Lead__c>)Leads){
             Map<String, Object> params = new Map<String, Object>();
                params.put('Campaign_ID', Ld.Campaign__c);
             
             system.debug('Parameters of Map'+params );
             
 Flow.Interview.Roll_Up_Summary_on_Lead RollupFlow = new Flow.Interview.Roll_Up_Summary_on_Lead(params);

             RollupFlow.start();
         }
    }    
}
```

Trigger:

```
trigger Rollupsummary on Lead__c (After Insert,After update, After Delete, After Undelete ) {

if (Trigger.isAfter && Trigger.Isinsert) {
RolleupsumLeads.afterinsert(Trigger.new);
}
}
```

Comment: Have you tried reducing the batch size to 1? I'm sure there are better workarounds

Comment: It is working with 1 batch size and not working with batch size of 200